# GnuPlot :: Plotting 3D recorded in an unconventional format

Tags: csv, gnuplot

I would like to prepare a script file to draw a 3D plot of some kinetic spectroscopy results. In the experiment the absorption spectrum of a solution is measured sequentially at increasing times from t<sub>0</sub> to t<sub>f</sub> with a constant increase in time Δt.
The plot will show the variation of absorbamce (Z) with wavelength and time.

The data are recorded using a UV-VIS spectrometer and saved as a CSV text file.

The file contains a table in which the first column are the wavelengths of the spectra. Afterwards, a column is added for each the measured spectra, and a number of columns depends on the total time and the time interval between measuerments. The time for each spectra appears in the headers line.

I wonder if the data can be plotted directly witha minimum of preformatting and without the need to rewrite the data in a more estandar XYZ format.

The structure of the data file is something like this

> Title; espectroscopia UV-Vis  
>   Comment;
>   Date; 23/10/2018 16:41:12 
>   Operator; laboratorios 
>   System Name; Undefined 
>   Wavelength (nm); 0 Min; 0,1 Min; 0,2 Min; 0,3 Min;    ...    28,5 Min 
>   400,5551; 1,491613E-03; 1,810312E-03; 2,01891E-03;    ...    4,755786E-03 
>   ...          ...           ...           ...          ...    ... 
>   799,2119; -5,509266E-04; 3,26314E-04;  -4,319865E-04; ... -5,087912E-04 
>   (EOF)

A copy of a sample data is included in this file [kinetic_spectroscopy.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/l/scl/AADe9wjYn3pgg630N09mWUGAkS2MODcqm88).

Thanks.

Comment: Could you use ```transpose``` [tag:excel]'s function on your data.

Comment: Ii is not a problem to transpose the data using Excel, but I do not understand how this change in the format of the data may help reading the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is in an acceptable form for gnuplot, but persuading the program to plot this as one line per wavelength rather than a gridded surface is more difficult.  First let's establish that the file can be read and plotted. The following commands should read in the x/y coordinates (x = first row, y = first column) and the z values to construct a surface.

```
DATA = 'espectros cinetica.csv'
set datafile separator ';'  # csv file with semicolon

                            # Your data uses , as a decimal point.
set decimal locale          # The program can handle this if your locale is correct.
show decimal                # confirm this by inspecting the output from "show".

set title DATA
set ylabel "Wavelength"
set xlabel "Time (min)"
set xyplane 0
set style data lines

splot DATA matrix nonuniform using 1:2:3 lc palette
```

[image]

This actually looks OK with your data.  For a smaller number of scans it is probably not what you would want.  In order to plot separate lines, one per scan, we could break this up into a sequence of line plots rather than a single surface plot:

```
 DATA = 'espectros cinetica.csv'
 set datafile separator ";"
 set decimal locale
 unset key
 set title DATA
 set style data lines
 set ylabel "Wavelength"
 set xlabel "Time (min)"
 set xtics offset 0,-1      # move labels away from axis

 splot for [row=0:*] DATA matrix nonuniform every :::row::row using 1:2:3
```

This is what I get for the first 100 rows of your data file.  The row data is colored sequentially by gnuplot linetypes.  Other coloring schemes are possible.
[image]

Comment: Both codes give me a good approach of I would like to like to achieve. I have run both of them on a Windows 7.0 computer using GnuPlot 5.2.7 with partial success. For the first script I've got a similar plot to yours but I semed to be more like an scatter plot than a grid and got the message  "espectros_cinetica.plt" line 13: warning: matrix contains missing or undefined values. For the second script I got a similar message but no plot.

Comment: Guess I need learning more about handling data and 3D plots in GnuPlot. Any suggestions where to start (from basics)?

Comment: The warning message is harmless.  It is possible that Windows is not setting your locale properly. Did you check that the output of `show decimal` confirms that it will recognize commas as decimal separators in the input file?   If that is not working, I would edit the data file to change all commas to periods.

Comment: Another thought.   I have "with lines" set as a default style.  You may have "with points" instead, which would change the appearance of the plot.  Try `splot DATA matrix nonuniform using 1:2:3 with lines lc palette`

Comment: Modifing the command as you mentioned I could reproduce your plot.